how to transfer USDT on pulsechain using ethers.js library in typescript?
I have using ethers.js library for transfer token on two networks : BEP-20 and Pulse-chain , when I send USDT on BEP-20 it works fine, but for USDT on pulsechain I get error gas estimate (missing revert data)
here is the message response of tx.wait() :
missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction=...
and my type script code is :

import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommandHandler, ICommandHandler } from '@nestjs/cqrs';
import { InternalServerError, Invalid_Network, Invalid_Token } from 'src/common/translates/Error.Translate';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { Request_Was_Successful1 } from 'src/common/translates/successful.Translate';
import { DepositCommand } from './deposit.command';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TokenEntity } from 'src/domains/transaction/entities/token.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@CommandHandler(DepositCommand)
export class DepositCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<DepositCommand> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TokenEntity)
        private readonly tokenRepository: Repository<TokenEntity>
    ) { }

    async execute(command: DepositCommand): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const { networkName, tokenName, amount, toAddress } = command.body;
            const token = await this.tokenRepository.findOne({
                where: [{
                    tokenName: tokenName,
                    networkName: networkName
                }]
            });
            if (!token) {
                throw new HttpException(Invalid_Token, Invalid_Token.status_code);
            }
            let wallet: any;
            const mainWalletPrivateKey = process.env.MAIN_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY;
            if (networkName.toLowerCase() == 'bep-20') {
                const bscProvider = await this.getResponsiveNode();
                wallet = new ethers.Wallet(mainWalletPrivateKey, bscProvider);
            } else if (networkName.toLowerCase() == 'pulse-chain') {
                const pulseChainProvider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc.pulsechain.com');
                // const pulseChainProvider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc-pulsechain.g4mm4.io');
                // const pulseChainProvider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://pulsechain-rpc.publicnode.com');
                wallet = new ethers.Wallet(mainWalletPrivateKey, pulseChainProvider);
            } else {
                throw new HttpException(Invalid_Network, Invalid_Network.status_code);
            }
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(token.contractAddress, JSON.parse(token.contractABI), wallet);
            const decimals = await contract.decimals();
            const amountInSmallestUnit = ethers.parseUnits(amount.toString(), decimals);

            for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= 5; attempt++) {
                const tx = await contract.transfer(toAddress, amountInSmallestUnit);
                const receipt = await tx.wait();
                console.log('receipt', receipt);
                if (receipt.status === 1) {
                    const Request_Was_Successful = Request_Was_Successful1({
                        tx_receipt_hash: receipt.hash
                    });
                    throw new HttpException(
                        {
                            ...Request_Was_Successful,
                        },
                        Request_Was_Successful.status_code,
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error);

            if (error.status === undefined) {
                const formatError = InternalServerError(error.message);
                throw new HttpException(formatError, formatError.status_code);
            } else throw error;
        }
    }

    async getResponsiveNode() {
        const rpcNodes = [
            'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/',
            'https://bsc-dataseed2.binance.org/',
            'https://bsc-dataseed3.binance.org/',
            'https://bsc-dataseed4.binance.org/'
        ];
        for (let node of rpcNodes) {
            try {
                const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(node);
                await provider.getBlockNumber();
                console.log(`Responsive node found: ${node}`);
                return provider;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`Node ${node} is not responsive.`);
            }
        }
        throw new Error('No responsive nodes found');
    }
}


I added the {gasLimit: 20000} to the transfer method and then it subract pls from my wallet and does not transfer the usdt :
                const tx = await contract.transfer(toAddress, amountInSmallestUnit, {gasLimit: 20000});
                const receipt = await tx.wait();

and return transaction reverted
thanks in advance
